# How to fetch records from same table using group by with where condition in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have a `cartitem` table I where there are two field named `vendor_id` and `cookie_identifier` I want to retrieve a specific cookie identifiers records group by vendor id..how can it possible. I write a query which is given bellow it does not work

```
$addTocartItems = CartItem::groupBy('vendor_id')
    ->where('cookie_identifier', $getCookieIdentifier)
    ->get();
```

Comment: With group by what you want vendor_id with count or something else

Comment: I have two records for vendor id 5 and one record for vendor id 4 for the cookie identifier 2105 ..after rnning this query i only get 1 records for vendor id 5 and 1 record for vendor id 3

Comment: @Shahrukh I want all records associated with vendor id 5 and vendor id 4 for with cookie id 2105

Comment: So why are you using group by statment just use a where clause and you get your desire output

Comment: I want to show vendor wise record  in the blade page